# activity indicator and CLLocation Distance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, uiactivityindicatorview

In my application i load at startup the distance between user location and a known point;
I want to show at startup an activity indicator with a label "Loading" that then disappears to show the distance. How can I do?

Comment: What part of the desired functionality you don't know how to implement? location / distance / showing the loading indicator / hiding it?

Comment: Only activty Indicator.
I have already set a label "Loading" that then disappears to show the distance, i need only that the activity indicator disappears when the distance is calculated and then shown;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build your views programmatically then this is how you instantiate the activity indicator view:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
```

If you use the IB then it is exactly like adding any other view...

In order to start animating use the `[activityIndicatorView startAnimating];` method.
In order to stop - use the `[activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];`.

In order to hide the label and the activity indicator together just put the inside an additional view (it might be full-screen half transparent view) and show/hide this view instead of label and indicator view separately.
This way you will also disable all the touchable UI elements (actually, you will hide these by the half-transparent loading view).

Comment: i have another idea, i set [indicator startAnimating] in viewDidLoad e then i set [indicator stopUpdating] in method that update the geographic location before 
distanceShow.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f",distance];
and works!!
;)